# is there a way to auto trim parts of my video when a specefic color or text shows up on those parts

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I play a game and record it, but unfortunately many parts of that recording is when my internet connection gets lost for several seconds. During that period it only shows a text that says "connection lost". Then the game resumes normally in few seconds after the connection is back.
Is there a software or a way that allows me to auto trim these connection lost periods from my viedeo? Please help I need to trim a lot of these periods so that I can post cool gaming videos online without the "connection lost" scenes included.

I tried searching on youtube and found some ffmpeg, python, and opencv methods but none of which is suitabal or easy to apply for my situation

Comment: "Any way"? Yes, absolutely; but it requires writing a lot of code. If you run into a _narrow, specific problem_ while writing that code, come back here; but the broad question is outside our scope.

Comment: As a rough pointer, though -- gstreamer is a library I've personally used for editing videos with quite a bit of success. OpenCV is popular these days for automating a lot of machine vision, though it's arguably massive overkill for what you're trying to do here; a very crude heuristic like "are all the pixels inside the first N lines within +/- X range of color Y?" should be more than sufficient.

Comment: But, and this is important, _software recommendation requests are explicitly off-topic on Stack Overflow_ (see #3 in the list of off-topic questions at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). We're here for narrow, specific questions about technical problems encountered while writing code, not for advising prebuilt tools suitable for a specific purpose.

Comment: thanks for the respond charles, but hey that's what I'm looking for:- something like jumpcutter.py but instead of working on trimming silent scens form videos; it works on cutting scens with specefic text when displayed from the video. I think the technology is not advanced enough for such thing or script to be easily accessable yet, unliss someone knows a method and is willing to share it online (prefarably through a youtube video which would be easy to understand) so that I wlill be entertained and able to produce my videos without manually and repatetively trimmig each unnecessary part

Comment: @Yousif K Al Ameen 1  What don't you understand about *software recommendation requests are explicitly off-topic on Stack Overflow* as stated above by Charles Duffy?

Comment: IIRC, you can ask gstreamer to give you a frame, so at that point it's a matter of comparing that frame against your expected values. That _should_ be reasonably straightforward -- exactly how much so depending on the amount of fuzziness (if content has already been through lossy compression you can't do an _exact_ comparison, but as mentioned above big chunks of a near-constant color should be really easy to detect). So if you set up a raw sink that just gives you a buffer full of RGB values, then comparing that buffer or a subset of it to expected values should just be a matter of iteration.

Comment: (well, iterating over the pixels in your chosen subset of the frame, determining how far they differ from the values you're looking for, and deciding whether that difference is over a threshold)

Comment: _but_ again, recommending off-site resources is outside our purview; tutorials, like software libraries, are explicitly listed in the link I gave above.

Comment: Well, here is something that you can play with in FFmpeg if you're still reading... Assuming that the "connection lost" screen is static (a fixed image), capture it as an image, feed it as a secondary input to FFmpeg, run `psnr` filter and detect and drop frames with high PSNR (i.e,, likely the connection lost frame) using `metadata` filter. This will require considerable amount of trial-n-error, but it could work if the connection lost frame is stationary. ...No, I have no working example, just an idea that you can try.

Comment: That is still very complicated for me guys. How about a script that I can paste in cmd and the only input I give it is the text to be deleted from the video, video file name and location, and then I hit Enter so that it can render my video fram by fram looking for that text and delete every fram containing that text in the output.